# How to pass NSArray from an NSObject class to a UIViewController class?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, viewcontroller, nsobject

I am new to Objective-C. I am trying to create a weather app where I parsed data from open weather map. I have stored the parsed data to an array. Now want to access the array value from other class but getting null value.

Can anyone help me?

What I have tried:

Here is my `NSObject` class where I am storing data and trying to send that to view controller:

```
- (void)getCurrentWeather:(NSString *)query
{
    NSString *const BASE_URL_STRING = @"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=";
    NSString *const API_KEY = @"&APPID=APIKEYSTRING";

    NSString *weatherURLText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",
    BASE_URL_STRING, query,API_KEY];
    NSURL *weatherURL = [NSURL URLWithString:weatherURLText];

    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:weatherURL];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedDataSmile | :) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];

    });
}

- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSString* cityName = [json objectForKey:@"name"];

    int currentTempCelsius = (int)[[[json objectForKey:@"main"] objectForKey:@"temp"] intValue] - ZERO_CELSIUS_IN_KELVIN;
    int maxTemp = (int)[[[json objectForKey:@"main"] objectForKey:@"temp_max"] intValue] - ZERO_CELSIUS_IN_KELVIN;
    int minTemp = (int)[[[json objectForKey:@"main"] objectForKey:@"temp_min"] intValue] - ZERO_CELSIUS_IN_KELVIN;
    NSString *weatherDescription = [[[json objectForKey:@"weather"] objectAtIndexBlush | :O ] objectForKey:@"description"];

    weatherArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:cityName, weatherDescription,
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", currentTempCelsius],
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", maxTemp],
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", minTemp],nil];
```

I have NSObject.h file as:

```
@interface WeatherData : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSString *weatherDescription;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *currentTemp;
@property (nonatomic) int maxTempCelsius;
@property (nonatomic) int minTempCelsius;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *weatherArray;

- (void)getCurrentWeather:(NSString *)query;

@end
```

In my view controller:

.h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *weatherResultArray;
```

.m file:

```
-(void)searchButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    WeatherData *weather = [[WeatherData alloc] init];
    [weather getCurrentWeather:_textField.text];
    self.weatherResultArray = weather.weatherArray;

    //temperatureLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d°",weather.currentTempCelsius];
}
```

I just want to show the results in UILabel.

Comment: From a quick glance at your code I believe you are getting NULL because the data has not yet returned from your http call when you try to access weather.weatherArray. So therefore self.weatherResultArray is NULL.

Comment: your return type is void in above function then how can i get array!

Comment: Passing data between view controllers is easy. For this you need to create a delegate function in NSObject.h. In that function, you create array for weather data. All, now you need is to add delegate in View Controller file and you will get data back, when delegate is being called.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried returning NSMutable array in this method

```
- (NSMutableArray*)getCurrentWeather:(NSString *)query
```

instead of this,

```
- (void)getCurrentWeather:(NSString *)query
```

This would be the easiest way to verify and also value can be retrieved in single statement as:

```
self.weatherResultArray = [weather getCurrentWeather:_textField.text];
```

One more thing, Don't forget to allocate and initialise your weatherResultArray as:

```
self.weatherResultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Answer (score 0):

In NSObject class, define a weather protocol.

```
//NSObject.h file
@protocol WeatherDelegate<NSObject>

-(void)getWeatherData:(YourNSObjectClass*)viewController getWeatherData:(NSMutableArray*)array;

@end
```

//NSObject.m file, in

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {

NSError* error;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSString* cityName = [json objectForKey:@"name"];

    int currentTempCelsius = (int)[[[json objectForKey:@"main"] objectForKey:@"temp"] intValue] - ZERO_CELSIUS_IN_KELVIN;
    int maxTemp = (int)[[[json objectForKey:@"main"] objectForKey:@"temp_max"] intValue] - ZERO_CELSIUS_IN_KELVIN;
    int minTemp = (int)[[[json objectForKey:@"main"] objectForKey:@"temp_min"] intValue] - ZERO_CELSIUS_IN_KELVIN;
    NSString *weatherDescription = [[[json objectForKey:@"weather"] objectAtIndexBlush | :O ] objectForKey:@"description"];

    weatherArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:cityName, weatherDescription,
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", currentTempCelsius],
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", maxTemp],
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", minTemp],nil];

   id<WeatherDelegate> strongDelegate = self.delegate;

    if ([strongDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(getWeatherData:getWeatherData:)])
    {
        [strongDelegate getWeatherData:self getWeatherData:weatherArray];
    }

}
```

In yourViewController class,Add this WeatherData protocol and add the delegate function in .m file to fetch the data.

```
@interface yourViewControllerClass()<WeatherDelegate>
{
   YourNSObjectClass *nsClass;
   NSMutableArray *dataArray;
}

-(void)getWeatherData:(YourNSObjectClass*)viewController getWeatherData:(NSMutableArray*)array{

 dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:array];

}

-(void)searchButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    WeatherData *weather = [[WeatherData alloc] init];
    [weather getCurrentWeather:_textField.text];
    self.weatherResultArray = dataArray;

    //temperatureLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d°",weather.currentTempCelsius];
}
```

Comment: This is general example, I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I am still getting problem.

Comment: which problem are u getting?